# javascript promise example with bluebird skips "then"

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, bluebird

I tried to find out about promises and I have a hard time now.
Here's my example that does not work:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>test page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bluebird.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
      function doTheThing () {
        return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
          setTimeout(function(){alert("2");},1000)
          alert("1");
        });
      }
      doTheThing().then(
        function() {
          alert("3");
        }, function(error) {
          alert("5");
        }
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This alerts "1" then "2" and that's it.

Why is "3" never alerted? Why does then() not execute at all?

Comment: Because your promise is neither resolved nor rejected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to resolve the Promise:

```
function doTheThing () {
   return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
     setTimeout(function(){ 
       alert("2"); 
       resolve(); 
     }, 1000)
     alert("1");
   });
 }
```

Imagine if your code took a callback argument, rather than returning a Promise:

```
function doTheThing (doneCallback) {
   setTimeout(function(){ 
     alert("2"); 
     doneCallback(); 
   }, 1000);
   alert("1");
 }
```

You'd need to call `doneCallback` to pass a value to the calling async code (or simply let it know it can continue, like in this case). Resolving (or rejecting) a Promise is analogous to that - it enables asynchronous flow control and value passing.

Answer (score 2):

A Promise must be `resolved` or `rejected` before it continues to pass execution on to the next `then` success or error handler. So in your `doTheThing` function you need to call `resolve`. I have amended your code a bit to demonstrate that by calling `resolve` you are passing control to the success handler, evident by the fact that the value `3` is given by calling `resolve("3")`.

```
function doTheThing () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){alert("2");},1000)
        alert("1");
        resolve("3");
    });
}

doTheThing().then(function(value) {
    alert(value);
}, function(error) {
    alert("5");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new Promise (function (fulfill, reject) {
    setTimeout(function(){alert("2");},1000)
    alert("1");
});
```

for a promise to be not pending, you have to fulfill (by executing the fulfill function, or reject (by executing the reject function), only then will the appropriate function in `.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` be fired

learn more about promises either [here](https://promisesaplus.com/) or [here](https://www.promisejs.org/)